# Can you catch python exception at a higher level and continue running from where the raise was made?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

For example:

```
def f():
    a()
    b()
    c()

def main():
     f()
```

I want to be able to catch the exception that `a` raises if it does and continue to `b` like it didn't happen.
Can it be done?

Comment: What's wrong with `try`ing the individual calls within `f`?

Comment: put `try` clause on `a`, and put b in the `except` clause.

Comment: I want to be able to catch from the main so I can decide what happens from outside the method

Comment: "so I can decide what happens from outside the method"   But you already decided that you want to call `b`. Do you have an actual use case for what you are looking for?